# Load color for setForeground from config.properties

Tags: java

hey is there any way to make this code to load color from config.properties ?

```
font.setForeground(new Color(configi.getProperty("fonts_colo")));
```

my config.properties

```
fonts_colo=44, 44, 44
```

Is there any good way to do that ?

Comment: What is Color? `java.awt.Color`, `javafx.scene.paint.Color`, or yet another class?

Comment: ```import java.awt.Color;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

**Parse the input string from properties**

```
var colFromProp = "44, 44, 44";
var rgb = Arrays.stream(colFromProp.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();
var c = new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
```

**Use another constructor**

Instead of taking a list of ints, you can use a constructor that takes a single int (typically given in hex format)

See [public Color(int rgb)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int))

```
var colFromProp = "0x2c2c2c";
var c = new Color(Integer.decode(colFromProp));
```

or

```
var colFromProp = "2c2c2c";
var c = new Color(Integer.parseInt(colFromProp, 16));
```

Comment: Dzięki :P
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't use a library which has some kind of config support you have to do that yourself.
For this purpose I'd recommend you to write a own class (Config.java e.g.) and load the whole config in the constructor (each line consists of key=value, you could use an extra Class "Attribute" for this pair, in which you could even implement to parse the value data, for example:

```
...
if(value!=null&&key!=null&&key.equals("fonts_colo")){
 String[] parts = value.split(", ");
 assert(parts!=null&&parts.length == 3);
 Color c = new Color(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
 //TODO: do something with the color
}
...
```

This way you are able to load more than one property, it is not too much work and you can reuse that class. 
If you actually want to use a library you could do something JSON based e.g. (even xml if your config gets more complicated)
I hope I could help :)

EDIT: possible implementation of such a class

```
public class Config {
private HashMap<String, Property> properties = new HashMap<>();
public Config(File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;){
        if(line.contains("=")) {
            String[] parts = line.split("=");
            assert(parts.length==2);
            properties.put(parts[0], new Property(parts[1]));
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
public Property getProperty(String key) {
    return properties.get(key);
}
/**
 * Returns a color represented by the property value of the given key.
 * @param key the key of the property
 * @return the color, if the value had the form "r, g, b" with r,g,b as integers, else null
 */
public Color getPropertyAsColor(String key) {
    Property p = getProperty(key);
    if(p == null || p.valueparts == null || p.valueparts.length != 3) return null;
    return new Color(Integer.parseInt(p.valueparts[0]), 
            Integer.parseInt(p.valueparts[1]), 
            Integer.parseInt(p.valueparts[2]));
}
private class Property{
    private String value;
    private String[] valueparts;
    public Property(String value) {
        if(value.contains(",")) 
            valueparts = value.split(",");
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String[] getValues() {
        if(valueparts == null)
            return new String[] {value};
        else return valueparts;
    }
}
```

}

with that you could do that:

```
Config c = new Config(new File("config.properties"));
...
font.setForeground(c.getPropertyAsColor("fonts_color"));
```

Comment: i would prefer to use from my config.properties than create another class, there need to be way to make this

Comment: @Barry what do you exactly mean? there is no native properties support in Java. And in your example configi is obviously an object from a class. Wait a minute I write you an example.

Comment: There is shorter way showed by Lesiak and for now it works fine :)

Comment: well its actually the same but with functional methods and without file loading